# Java object creation ,a twisted one

Tags: java, object

What is object in java ,is it just the memory area in buffer or as the definition say ?Is it created after the new operator ?So why do we use class constructor at end?

Comment: Oh my little Jesus. Please refer some java guide before start asking questions.

Comment: You need to do some reading to be able to understand the answer.  You are asking both basic and very advanced questions and you need to do some research first.  I have tried to answer these sort of questions before and it wasn't helpful.

Comment: it's not that way ...it's simple I know what objects are and how we define but the question is if it is already created after new operator why do we require classs constructor.

Comment: @dream123 What if you want to provide some parameters to the Class which you are creating Object ? the name it self telling that to Construct the Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is object in java** --> An object is an instance of a class.

**is it just the memory area in buffer or as the definition say** --> It occupies some memory.

**Is it created after the new operator** --> Yes

**So why do we use class constructor at end** --> To initialize the state of fields in the object.

Answer (score 1):

Normally I wouldn't answer such an under researched question but as they say "you don't know, what you don't know" so...

A Java [object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html) is an instance of a Java [class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html) created with the `new` keyword and stored in the [heap space](http://javaeesupportpatterns.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/java-heap-space-what-is-it.html) in memory and referred to by it's variable name.

```
 MyClass classVariableName = new MyClass();  //Create object of type MyClass and refer to it with the name 'classVariableName'
```

When `new` is called on a class, the constructor of that class is called on the object being created to allow you some control over creation.  For example, setting the default values of member variables.

More detailed description [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

Comment: thanks ross for your kind support.

Answer (score 0):

Say you've got Test object

```
 Test test1 = new Test();
```

whenever your creating object using new operator that time object is created in heap space.and it return memory location, 
Here your are creating Test Class object and that object's memory location is saving in test1 reference varible.